# Debug gdb setup

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, static-libraries, gdbserver

I have a situation in which I'm remotely debugging an application which uses a static library. Both the static library and the application are built with the `-g` flag, and there are debug entries shown on `objdump -t lib.a | grep debug`.

However, the debugger only stops the breakpoints in the functions of the main application, but ignores the ones in the static lib. I do a print statement in the lib which gets executed but a breakpoint on the same place is ignored. The lib source is also available. I'm using Qt creator for the debugging interface.

My question is if there is a way to debug this setup? Can gdb print some log messages at run time that could point to the error?

Comment: When you say "the debugger only notices the breakpoints in the main application, but ignores the ones in the static lib", does that mean that you can set breakpoints in the debugger with no errors being reported, but the program doesn't stop at those breakpoints?  Or does it stop at the breakpoints but the debugger doesn't identify the stop reason as a breakpoint?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I've updated the question. The debugger doesn't stop even though there is a breakpoint and code at that location is certainly executed.

Answer (score 1):

what does it say when you set the breakpoint? type:

```
info b
```

and see if your breakpoints are enabled. If you have optimization enabled, the code that you refer to may be optimized out.

Comment: Traced the issue to a `No source file named /home/user/path_to_source`